# Getting multiple rows of same row with just one column change from database

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm using following query to fetch record from database. It has join with to many other tables. Everything work fine but problem is I'm getting multiple rows of same reservation and it's because reservation table has join with payment table and payment table has multiple rows against one reservation that's why it repeat complete record. What I want is to show single row having all payments rows in it so that I can loop through all payments and display them instead of displaying entire reservation record again and again. below is my query. It's Laravel 5.2.

```
return $results = DB::table('resorts_reservation')
            ->join('resorts_resort', 'resorts_reservation.resortId', '=', 'resorts_resort.resortId')
            ->join('resorts_roomtype', 'resorts_reservation.roomTypeId', '=', 'resorts_roomtype.roomTypeId')
            ->join('resorts_customer', 'resorts_reservation.customerId', '=', 'resorts_customer.customerId')
            ->join('resorts_salesperson', 'resorts_reservation.salesPersonId', '=', 'resorts_salesperson.salesPersonId')
            ->join('resorts_payment', 'resorts_reservation.reservationId', '=', 'resorts_payment.reservationId')
            ->join('resorts_paymentmethod', 'resorts_payment.paymentMethodId', '=', 'resorts_paymentmethod.paymentMethodId')
            ->join('resorts_emailnotification', 'resorts_reservation.reservationId', '=', 'resorts_emailnotification.reservationId')
            ->join('resorts_resortcompany', 'resorts_resort.resortCompanyId', '=', 'resorts_resortcompany.resortCompanyId')
            ->select('resorts_reservation.totalAmount', 'resorts_reservation.saleDate', 'resorts_reservation.reservationId', 
                    'resorts_reservation.confirmNo', 'resorts_reservation.numberOfNights', 'resorts_reservation.checkInDate', 
                    'resorts_reservation.checkOutDate', 'resorts_reservation.numberOfAdults', 'resorts_reservation.numberOfChildren',
                    'resorts_reservation.totalInParty', 'resorts_reservation.notes', 'resorts_reservation.totalPrice',
                    'resorts_reservation.saleSource', 'resorts_reservation.depositAmount', 'resorts_reservation.confirmationSent',
                    'resorts_reservation.finalized',
                    'resorts_customer.firstName', 'resorts_customer.mobilePhone', 'resorts_customer.otherPhone',
                    'resorts_customer.email', 'resorts_customer.addressLineOne', 'resorts_customer.city',
                    'resorts_customer.country', 'resorts_customer.state_', 'resorts_customer.postalCode',
                    'resorts_resort.resortName', 
                    'resorts_roomtype.roomTypeDesc', 'resorts_roomtype.occupancy',
                    'resorts_salesperson.firstName as saleFirstName','resorts_salesperson.lastName as saleLastName',
                    'resorts_paymentmethod.methodType',
                    'resorts_payment.transactionNo',
                    'resorts_resortcompany.resortCompanyName')
            ->whereRaw($where)
            ->orderBy('reservationId', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Below is the result return from the query. You can see both rows has same record with just "transactionNo" column change.

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [totalAmount] => 2161.2
        [saleDate] => 2016-03-09 00:00:00
        [reservationId] => 30286
        [confirmNo] => 
        [numberOfNights] => 3
        [checkInDate] => 2016-04-22 00:00:00
        [checkOutDate] => 2016-04-25 00:00:00
        [numberOfAdults] => 6
        [numberOfChildren] => 0
        [totalInParty] => 6
        [notes] => 
        [totalPrice] => 2161.2
        [saleSource] => VRBO
        [depositAmount] => 2161.2
        [confirmationSent] => 0
        [finalized] => 0
        [firstName] => Michael
        [mobilePhone] => 505-321-2106
        [otherPhone] => 
        [email] => xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
        [addressLineOne] => 
        [city] => Albuquerque
        [country] => USA
        [state_] => NM
        [postalCode] => 87111
        [resortName] => San Francisco - Canterbury
        [roomTypeDesc] => 3 Bedroom Presidential
        [occupancy] => 6
        [saleFirstName] => Kristy
        [saleLastName] => Conlin
        [methodType] => CREDIT_CARD
        [transactionNo] => 7MG983973K453254C

        [resortCompanyName] => Wyndham
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [totalAmount] => 2161.2
        [saleDate] => 2016-03-09 00:00:00
        [reservationId] => 30286
        [confirmNo] => 
        [numberOfNights] => 3
        [checkInDate] => 2016-04-22 00:00:00
        [checkOutDate] => 2016-04-25 00:00:00
        [numberOfAdults] => 6
        [numberOfChildren] => 0
        [totalInParty] => 6
        [notes] => 
        [totalPrice] => 2161.2
        [saleSource] => VRBO
        [depositAmount] => 2161.2
        [confirmationSent] => 0
        [finalized] => 0
        [firstName] => Michael
        [mobilePhone] => 505-321-2106
        [otherPhone] => 
        [email] => xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
        [addressLineOne] => 
        [city] => Albuquerque
        [country] => USA
        [state_] => NM
        [postalCode] => 87111
        [resortName] => San Francisco - Canterbury
        [roomTypeDesc] => 3 Bedroom Presidential
        [occupancy] => 6
        [saleFirstName] => Kristy
        [saleLastName] => Conlin
        [methodType] => CREDIT_CARD
        [transactionNo] => 
        [resortCompanyName] => Wyndham
    )
```

What I want is something like below:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [totalAmount] => 2161.2
        [saleDate] => 2016-03-09 00:00:00
        [reservationId] => 30286
        [confirmNo] => 
        [numberOfNights] => 3
        [checkInDate] => 2016-04-22 00:00:00
        [checkOutDate] => 2016-04-25 00:00:00
        [numberOfAdults] => 6
        [numberOfChildren] => 0
        [totalInParty] => 6
        [notes] => 
        [totalPrice] => 2161.2
        [saleSource] => VRBO
        [depositAmount] => 2161.2
        [confirmationSent] => 0
        [finalized] => 0
        [firstName] => Michael
        [mobilePhone] => 505-321-2106
        [otherPhone] => 
        [email] => xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
        [addressLineOne] => 
        [city] => Albuquerque
        [country] => USA
        [state_] => NM
        [postalCode] => 87111
        [resortName] => San Francisco - Canterbury
        [roomTypeDesc] => 3 Bedroom Presidential
        [occupancy] => 6
        [saleFirstName] => Kristy
        [saleLastName] => Conlin
        [methodType] => CREDIT_CARD
        array(
            [transactionNo] => 7MG983973K453254C
            [transactionNo] => 
        )
        [resortCompanyName] => Wyndham
    )
```

Comment: If you want to show only one reservation you can GROUPBY("reservationId"). If you want to show all payments for one reservation separately, I would create another query just for payments and show the payment id/transactionNo.

Not sure what you mean by:
"show single row having all payments rows in it" maybe you can elaborate on it.

Comment: #Tom I've update my question. I want one row against one reservation but this row should have multiple payment rows against that reservation like the one I've added in updated question. By this handling it will become easier in controller or view.

Comment: Ok, now it makes sense. I wrote an answer below, take a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GROUP-CONCAT function to group all payment transaction numbers for each reservation.

From [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

> This function returns a string result with the concatenated non-NULL
>   values from a group. It returns NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

Your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT resorts_reservation.totalAmount, ..., GROUP_CONCAT(resorts_payment.transactionNo separator ', ') as transactionNoList
WHERE...
```

Hope this makes sense, if not, I will be glad to clarify.

Tom Rushman

Comment: Used this but now it return only one row with all Payment transactionNo  in it separated by ",". I want my query to return all reservation with payment.transactionNo related to reservationId. Like if reservation 1 has 2 payments then it should return 1 row of reservation with 2 payments records related to that specific reservation. and if there are now payment for some reservation it should still return reservation row with empty payment.

Comment: You should also GROUP BY reservationId so that all payments that relate to that reservation will only be grouped to it.

Comment: no it didn't worked even after using GROUP BY, with this it return 1 reservation with only 1 payment row not all payments row related to that reservation

Comment: Hmm, are you sure you have more than one reservation? Regardless of the change, you should have multiple rows for reservations (with different IDs).